Restore a TWRP Backup through Odin?
Is there a way to convert TWRP Backup to an Odin Flashable Tar file?
I have a TWRP Backup of my old LineageOS 20 for my phone, but currently I don't have a working TWRP because of this issue: TWRP Black Screen on Samsung Galaxy A9 2018
I want to be able to get back to this LineageOS 20, but without TWRP is there a way to convert the backup to an Odin Flashable Tar and flash it through Odin?
TWRP Backup contains all these files:
boot.emmc.win
boot.emmc.win.sha2
cache.ext4.win
cache.ext4.win.sha2
cache.info
data.ext4.win
data.ext4.win.sha2
data.info
dsp.emmc.win
dsp.emmc.win.sha2
efs.ext4.win
efs.ext4.win.sha2
efs.info
efsc.emmc.win
efsc.emmc.win.sha2
efsg.emmc.win
efsg.emmc.win.sha2
modem.emmc.win
modem.emmc.win.sha2
modemst1.emmc.win
modemst1.emmc.win.sha2
modemst2.emmc.win
modemst2.emmc.win.sha2
odm.ext4.win
odm.ext4.win.sha2
odm.info
odm_image.emmc.win
odm_image.emmc.win.sha2
recovery.emmc.win
recovery.emmc.win.sha2
recovery.log
system.ext4.win000
system.ext4.win000.sha2
system.ext4.win001
system.ext4.win001.sha2
system.info
system_image.emmc.win
system_image.emmc.win.sha2
vendor_image.emmc.win
vendor_image.emmc.win.sha2

